# Create boot entry in bcdedit for Windows 8 to go

Tags: windows, bootloader, bcdedit

WI created a "Windows 8 to go" drive and attached it (to a SATA port) on to a windows 7 laptop (instead of CD drive). I'd like to modify the Windows 7 boot configuration (`bcdedit`) to boot Windows 8 from the another drive. I tried to create a new entry in `bcdedit`, but it keep loads windows recovery. I created a copy of current and set `device` and `osdevice` to `partition=E:`.

**The question is**: How to create the right boot entry?

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \bootmgr
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {c71c7fc9-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
displayorder            {current}
                        {c71c7fce-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {c71c7fcb-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {c71c7fc9-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
nx                      OptIn

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {c71c7fce-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 8
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {c71c7fcb-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=E:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {c71c7fc9-e003-11e1-b23d-5c260a473966}
nx                      OptIn
```

ps.: I doesn't have access to the bios, so I can't boot it directly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "Dual-boot Repair" tool from [Visual BCD package](http://www.boyans.net)

Run tool, click "Automatic Repair" and see if will pick up Windows 8 from attached device.

If yes confirm. The result will be a new boot loader for Windows 8 (and a new boot menu entry).

Don't worry, your current BCD will be backed up in case something goes wrong. Please note backup location on paper.

**Have a Windows 7 recovery CD/USB ready for the worst scenario !**
(BCD can be restored/imported using bcdedit.)

There are people changing boot configurations without thinking of having installation/recovery media ready and then go on forums asking for help.

Feedback would be great.